# Wait Cursor Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm coding an advanced web browser. The bad thing is, is that whenever you move your cursor over the window, a wait cursor is displayed. I tried to deselect the wait cursor but it doesn't work!

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Beta 2...

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

check UseWaitCursor at false in the properties!